# Difficulty connecting Python3 to a MariaDB - take 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mariadb, mysql-python

See related question at: [Difficulty connecting python3 to a mariadb - take2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048931/difficulty-connecting-python3-to-a-mariadb-take2)

I have Python2.7 and python3 installed on an OpenSuse (Leap 15.1) and I have I have MariaDB installed

```
uname -a              Linux TRANQUILITY 4.12.14-lp151.28.13-default #1 SMP Wed Aug 7 07:20:16 UTC 2019 (0c09ad2) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
python2.7 --version   Python 2.7.14
python3 --version     Python 3.6.5
mysql --version       mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.25-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

My program is meant to parse a folder full of csv files, check whether the file is a CSV and then, if it is, check in a DB table whether that file has been parsed before. Unfortunately, it will not connect to the DB!

On a bash console, I can easily connect to the DB  but running my python script returns the following:

```
Attempting to connect to DB: SunnyData2 <--my debug print 
OK, going for it next! <--my debug print
DB read failed! <----python response
None <--my debug print
```

I have searched StackOverflow & Google and it appears that the `MySQLdb` driver I'm using doesn't work on Python3, so I've changed the top of the file to invoke python 2.7, instead of python 3

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

from

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

but that didn't help (same return message), so with python 3 I've also tried importing `mysql-connector-python` instead of `MySQLdb`

but then I got a warning that that driver didn't exist/wasn't recognised!

My imports are:

```
from os import listdir
from datetime import datetime #could this just be 'import datetime'?
import MySQLdb
import shutil
import syslog
import os, sys
```

and my function for establishing a db connection is this:

```
def connect_to_DB(action):
    """
    Connect to the DB
    """
    h="localhost", # host
    u="root", # username
    p="p/w redacted"
    d = "db name redacted"
    if action == 'connect':
        #SD.close()
        print 'Attempting to connect to DB: ' + d
        try:
            print "OK, going for it next!"
            SD = MySQLdb.connect(host=h, user=u, password=p, database=d)
            syslog.syslog('Connected to DB')
            print "Connection Object: " + SD
            return SD
        except Exception as e:
            syslog.syslog('Failed to connect to DB')
            return False
    elif action == 'disconnect':
        try:
            #mariadb_connection.close()
            SD.close()
            syslog.syslog('Disconnected from DB')
            return 'closed'
        except Exception as e:
            syslog.syslog('Failed to disconnect from DB')
            return False
```

Any suggestions?

I have now made the following suggested changes:

1. removed the `try` & `except`
2. changed the MySQL connection to these (tried one at a time, obvs)
   but neither worked:`SD = MySQLdb.connect(str(h), str(u), str(p), str(d))` and `SD = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='aPassword', db='blah')`
3. verified that localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1
4. ran python2.7 with the -v flag with this output (sorry for posting
   it all but I don't know which parts may be relevant)

```
python2.7 -v ./SunnyCSV2DB.py 
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/types.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/types.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/re.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/re.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so", 2);
import _locale # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
import encodings # directory /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.14 (default, Oct 12 2017, 15:50:02) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so", 2);
import datetime # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
import MySQLdb # directory /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py
import MySQLdb # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/release.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/release.py
import MySQLdb.release # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/release.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.so", 2);
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_exceptions.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_exceptions.py
import MySQLdb._exceptions # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_exceptions.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/compat.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/compat.py
import MySQLdb.compat # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/compat.pyc
import MySQLdb._mysql # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.so
import MySQLdb.constants # directory /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py
import MySQLdb.constants # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py
import MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/times.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/times.py
import MySQLdb.times # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/times.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so", 2);
import time # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py
import shutil # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/fnmatch.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/fnmatch.py
import fnmatch # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/fnmatch.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.py
import collections # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/collections.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so", 2);
import _collections # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so", 2);
import operator # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/keyword.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/keyword.py
import keyword # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/keyword.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/heapq.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/heapq.py
import heapq # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/heapq.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so", 2);
import itertools # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so", 2);
import _heapq # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
import thread # builtin
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so", 2);
import zlib # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/bz2.so", 2);
import bz2 # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/bz2.so
import pwd # builtin
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/grp.so", 2);
import grp # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/grp.so
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/syslog.so", 2);
import syslog # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/syslog.so
Attempting to connect to DB: SunnyData2
OK, going for it next!
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py
import MySQLdb.connections # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py
import MySQLdb.cursors # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/__future__.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/__future__.py
import __future__ # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/__future__.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/functools.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/functools.py
import functools # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/functools.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so", 2);
import _functools # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py
import MySQLdb.constants.CLIENT # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/converters.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/converters.py
import MySQLdb.converters # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/converters.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/decimal.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/decimal.py
import decimal # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/decimal.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so", 2);
import math # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/numbers.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/numbers.py
import numbers # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/numbers.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py
import threading # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/locale.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/locale.py
import locale # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/locale.pyc
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py
import MySQLdb.constants.FLAG # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so", 2);
import array # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
# /usr/lib64/python2.7/weakref.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python2.7/weakref.py
import weakref # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.7/weakref.pyc
DB read failed!
None
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] datetime
# cleanup[1] sysconfig
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] decimal
# cleanup[1] threading
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] google
# cleanup[1] locale
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb
# cleanup[1] encodings
# cleanup[1] abc
# cleanup[1] math
# cleanup[1] _functools
# cleanup[1] thread
# cleanup[1] weakref
# cleanup[1] itertools
# cleanup[1] __future__
# cleanup[1] _collections
# cleanup[1] operator
# cleanup[1] _heapq
# cleanup[1] sre_constants
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup[1] _codecs
# cleanup[1] pwd
# cleanup[1] _sysconfigdata
# cleanup[1] keyword
# cleanup[1] syslog
# cleanup[1] zlib
# cleanup[1] posix
# cleanup[1] encodings.aliases
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.release
# cleanup[1] site
# cleanup[1] numbers
# cleanup[1] shutil
# cleanup[1] bz2
# cleanup[1] grp
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.converters
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.compat
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.constants
# cleanup[1] _weakref
# cleanup[1] _weakrefset
# cleanup[1] time
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE
# cleanup[1] functools
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.times
# cleanup[1] collections
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb._exceptions
# cleanup[1] encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.connections
# cleanup[1] fnmatch
# cleanup[1] codecs
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.constants.FLAG
# cleanup[1] traceback
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.constants.CLIENT
# cleanup[1] array
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb._mysql
# cleanup[1] MySQLdb.cursors
# cleanup[1] heapq
# cleanup[1] re
# cleanup[1] _locale
# cleanup[1] sre_compile
# cleanup[1] _sre
# cleanup[1] sre_parse
# cleanup[2] UserDict
# cleanup[2] posixpath
# cleanup[2] errno
# cleanup[2] os.path
# cleanup[2] copy_reg
# cleanup[2] linecache
# cleanup[2] _abcoll
# cleanup[2] genericpath
# cleanup[2] stat
# cleanup[2] warnings
# cleanup[2] types
# cleanup[2] os
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 40 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats: 3 unfreed floats
```

Comment: Get rid of the try/except temporarily so you can see the whole stack trace then post it here. RIght now the exception is hidden so not much use.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SunnyCSV2DB.py", line 212, in <module>
    connection = connect_to_DB('connect') # TRUE, if connected successfully
  File "./SunnyCSV2DB.py", line 82, in connect_to_DB
    SD = MySQLdb.connect(h, u, p, d)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 164, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: connect() argument 1 must be string, not tuple

Comment: Sorry. Couldn't see how to format it properly but it looks like it's down to the format of the connection params?

Comment: I changed to SD = MySQLdb.connect(str(h), str(u), str(p), str(d)) and now the response is MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '('localhost',)' (-2)")

Comment: in /etc/hosts I have 127.0.0.1 mapped to localhost

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you've misnamed some of your parameters. That might be confusing it into thinking you're giving it a tuple, although not sure why. Should be `passwd` and `db`

https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#connection-objects

Comment: I've made some of the suggested edits but without success. I have much more verbose output on StdOut, so I'm really interested in any further insights into this?