# Difficulty connecting python3 to a mariadb - take2

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, pymysql

I asked a previous question with the same title but none of the suggestions worked. I thought a supplementary question with a distillation of all the avenues tried would make for a clearer question than trying to shoehorn it into the original post (but maintain all the feedback from the original: [Difficulty connecting Python3 to a MariaDB - take 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57939481/difficulty-connecting-python3-to-a-mariadb)) - please let me know (politely) if there's an alternative preferred approach

I have Python2.7 and python3 installed on an OpenSuse (Leap 15.1) and I have I have MariaDB installed

```
uname -a              Linux TRANQUILITY 4.12.14-lp151.28.13-default #1 SMP Wed Aug 7 07:20:16 UTC 2019 (0c09ad2) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
python2.7 --version   Python 2.7.14
python3 --version     Python 3.6.5
mysql --version       mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.25-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

My program is meant to parse a folder full of csv files, check whether the file is a CSV and then, if it is, check in a DB table whether that file has been parsed before. The python script (permissions:`754`)  and all the csv files (permissions:`644`) are in the same folder.

**Unfortunately, it will not connect to the DB from the script!**

Using *exactly the same* credentials and from the same path (ie the folder with the csvs & py script):

- From a bash console, I can easily connect to the DB

```
me@server:/project/dataCSVs> mysql -u root -p 
Enter password: <myPW>
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 45
Server version: 10.2.25-MariaDB SUSE package
<snip>
MariaDB [(none)]> use myDB;
<snip>
Database changed
MariaDB [myDB]> show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_myDB |
+----------------------+
| DTP                  |
| Files                |
+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

- From the Python3 console and using `import pymysql`, I can easily connect to the DB

```
me@server:/project/dataCSVs> python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 31 2018, 19:45:04) [GCC] on linux
<snip>
>>> import pymysql;
>>> SD = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='myPW', database='myDB', port=3306);
>>> print(SD);
<pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x7fae9d277978>
```

- From within my Python script, using `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` & `import MySQLdb`, I cannot connect to the DB
- From within my Python script, using `#!/usr/bin/python3` & `import pymysql`, I cannot connect to the DB

Concentrating on the `pymysql` driver & `python3`, the function and relevant additional bits in my code that tries to connect is:

```
from os import listdir
from datetime import datetime
import pymysql
import shutil
import syslog
import os, sys

<snipped>

def connect_to_DB(action):
    """
    Connect to the DB
    """
    h  = "127.0.0.1", # host
    u  = "root", # username
    p  = "myPW" # password
    d  = "myDB" # database
    Pt = 3306 # port
    if action == 'connect':
        print('Attempting to connect to DB: ' + d)
        print("OK, going for it next!")
        # tried all three of these connect options
        SD = pymysql.connect(host=str(h), user=str(u), passwd=str(p), db=str(d), port=Pt)
        #SD = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='myPW', db='myDB', port=3306)
        #SD = pymysql.connect(str(h), str(u), str(p), str(d), Pt)
        syslog.syslog('Connected to DB')
        return SD
    elif action == 'disconnect':
        SD.close()
        syslog.syslog('Disconnected from DB')
        return 'closed'

<snipped>

# Main start of program
<snipped - commented out everything apart from connect and disconnect to DB>
connection = connect_to_DB('connect') 
<snipped>
disconnection = connect_to_DB('disconnect')
```

Invoked with `python3 myScript.py`, I get:

```
me@MyServer:/project/dataCSVs> python3 myScript.py
Attempting to connect to DB: myDB
OK, going for it next!
DB read failed!
None
```

Invoked with `python3 -v myScript.py`, I get (I've only pasted the parts that seems relevant, i.e.  a reference to pymysql):

```
me@server:/project/dataCSVs> python3 -v myScript.py
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
               <snipped>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc'
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/_compat.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/_compat.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/_compat.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql._compat' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37cca9240>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__init__.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.constants' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37cca9358>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/FIELD_TYPE.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/FIELD_TYPE.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.constants.FIELD_TYPE' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37cca94e0>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/converters.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/converters.cpython-36.pyc'
# /usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/decimal.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python3.6/decimal.py
               <snipped>
import 're' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37cc92b38>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/FLAG.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/FLAG.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/FLAG.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.constants.FLAG' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37c8179e8>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/charset.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/charset.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/charset.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.charset' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37c817b38>
import 'pymysql.converters' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37cca96a0>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/err.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/err.cpython-36.pyc'
# /usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/struct.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python3.6/struct.py
# code object from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/struct.cpython-36.pyc'
# extension module '_struct' loaded from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module '_struct' executed from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
import '_struct' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc37c55eac8>
import 'struct' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37c55e898>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/ER.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/ER.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/ER.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.constants.ER' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37c55ec50>
import 'pymysql.err' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37cca9b00>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/times.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/times.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/times.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.times' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37cca9be0>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/connections.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/connections.cpython-36.pyc'
# /usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python3.6/__future__.py
               <snipped>
import 'traceback' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37c594278>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/CLIENT.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/CLIENT.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/CLIENT.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.constants.CLIENT' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37b5f8da0>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/COMMAND.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/COMMAND.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/COMMAND.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.constants.COMMAND' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37b5fe080>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/CR.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/CR.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/CR.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.constants.CR' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37b5fe128>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/SERVER_STATUS.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/SERVER_STATUS.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/constants/__pycache__/SERVER_STATUS.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.constants.SERVER_STATUS' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37b5fe0f0>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/cursors.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/cursors.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.cursors' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37b5fe208>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/optionfile.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/optionfile.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/optionfile.cpython-36.pyc'
# /usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/configparser.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python3.6/configparser.py
# code object from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/configparser.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'configparser' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37b171320>
import 'pymysql.optionfile' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37b1710f0>
# /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/util.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/util.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__pycache__/util.cpython-36.pyc'
import 'pymysql.util' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37b11d6a0>
# /usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/ssl.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py
               <snipped>
import 'getpass' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37b11dc88>
import 'pymysql.connections' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37c55eba8>
import 'pymysql' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37ccc8240>
# /usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/shutil.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python3.6/shutil.py
               <snipped>
import 'syslog' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc37c58d4e0>
Attempting to connect to DB: SunnyData2
OK, going for it next!
# /usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/idna.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/idna.py
# code object from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/encodings/__pycache__/idna.cpython-36.pyc'
# /usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/stringprep.cpython-36.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python3.6/stringprep.py
# code object from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/__pycache__/stringprep.cpython-36.pyc'
# extension module 'unicodedata' loaded from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module 'unicodedata' executed from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
import 'unicodedata' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc379d65550>
import 'stringprep' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc379d601d0>
import 'encodings.idna' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fc37aa4add8>
DB read failed!
None
```

Comment: `passwd` to `password`, and if there is no error then it is not the problem of the package but your connection might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the pymysql docs at https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html

and changed both `passwd` to `password` and `db` to `database` but I'm still getting the same error. Both Python & mysql are on the SAME machine and I can log in from Bash and Python consoles, just not the Python script.

Comment: I've added in the Bash & Python console connection commands and responses into the main body of the question, for reference.

Comment: is your id allowed to access the db with grant permission from 127.0.0.1? might be localhost?

Comment: Yes. I suspect I wouldn't have been able to log in from Bash & Python consoles if it didn't. Also my hosts file has `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` mapped

Comment: I have got it working but not in the way I think it should work - if I use `SD = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='myPW', database='myDB', port=3306)`, it works, but if I use `SD = pymysql.connect(host=h, user=u, password=p, database=d, port=Pt)`, where h,u,p,d are strings and Pt is an integer, it doesn't work. See the function in the main body of the question for the code in context.

Comment: Rather embarrassingly, I just spotted why the above was true. I had trailing commas on my authorization variables. And this is why, despite enjoying coding, I get frustrated and could never do it as a job - I'm too slapdash and miss these details.